# Rule for invoking subshell in Bash?

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, subshell

I seem to misunderstand the Bash rule for creating a subshell. I thought parentheses always creates a subshell, which runs as its own process.

However, this doesn't seem to be the case. In Code Snippet A (below), the second `sleep` command does not run in a separate shell (as determined by `pstree` in another terminal). However, in Code Snippet B, the second `sleep` command *does* run in a separate shell. The only difference between the snippets is that the second snippet has two commands within the parentheses.

Could somebody please explain the rule for when subshells are created?

**CODE SNIPPET A:**

```
sleep 5
(
sleep 5
)
```

**CODE SNIPPET B:**

```
sleep 5
(
x=1
sleep 5
)
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The parentheses always start a subshell. What's happening is that bash detects that `sleep 5` is the last command executed by that subshell, so it calls `exec` instead of [`fork`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_%28operating_system%29)+[`exec`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Execve). The `sleep` command replaces the subshell in the same process.

In other words, the base case is:

1. `( … )` create a subshell. The original process calls `fork` and `wait`. In the subprocess, which is a subshell:

   1. `sleep` is an external command which requires a subprocess of the subprocess. The subshell calls `fork` and `wait`. In the subsubprocess:

      1. The subsubprocess executes the external command → `exec`.
      2. Eventually the command terminates → `exit`.
   2. `wait` completes in the subshell.
2. `wait` completes in the original process.

The optimization is:

1. `( … )` create a subshell. The original process calls `fork` and `wait`. In the subprocess, which is a subshell until it calls `exec`:

   1. `sleep` is an external command, and it's the last thing this process needs to do.
   2. The subprocess executes the external command → `exec`.
   3. Eventually the command terminates → `exit`.
2. `wait` completes in the original process.

When you add something else after the call the `sleep`, the subshell needs to be kept around, so this optimization can't happen.

When you add something else before the call to `sleep`, the optimization could be made (and ksh does it), but bash doesn't do it (it's very conservative with this optimization).

Comment: [Subshell is created by calling `fork` and child process is created (to execute external commands) by calling `fork + exec`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/157962/186463). But your first para suggests that `fork + exec` is called for subshell too. What I am getting wrong here?

Comment: @haccks `fork`+`exec` is not called for the subshell, it's called for the external command. Without any optimization, there's a `fork` call for the subshell and another one for the external command. I've added a detailed flow description to my answer.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the update. Now it explains better. I can deduce from it  that in case of `(...)` (in base case), there may or may not be a call to `exec` depends on whether the subshell has any external command to execute, while in case of executing any external command there must be `fork + exec`.

Comment: One more question: Is this optimisation works only for subshell or it can be done for a command like `date` in a shell?

Comment: @haccks I don't understand the question. This optimization is about invoking an external command as the last thing a shell process does. It isn't restricted to subshells: compare `strace -f -e clone,execve,write bash -c 'date'` and `strace -f -e clone,execve,write bash -c 'date; true'`

Comment: I am talking about a simple command in a shell: `date`. As it is an external command so shell will first `fork` a new process and then use `exec`. But is that the case that shell only call `exec` as `date` is the only command to processed by the shell?

Comment: @haccks It depends on the shell, on what comes before the command and on what's around it. Calling `exec` directly is an optimization.

Comment: Considering bash and the only command is `date` (nothing around it).

Answer (score 6):

From the [Advanced Bash Programming Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/subshells.html):

"In general, an external command in a script forks off a subprocess, whereas a Bash builtin does not. For this reason, builtins execute more quickly and use fewer system resources than their external command equivalents."

And a little further down:

"A command list embedded between parentheses runs as a subshell."

Examples:

```
[root@talara test]# echo $BASHPID
10792
[root@talara test]# (echo $BASHPID)
4087
[root@talara test]# (echo $BASHPID)
4088
[root@talara test]# (echo $BASHPID)
4089
```

Example using OPs code (with shorter sleeps because I am impatient):

```
echo $BASHPID

sleep 2
(
    echo $BASHPID
    sleep 2
    echo $BASHPID
)
```

The output:

```
[root@talara test]# bash sub_bash
6606
6608
6608
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Tim. I'm not sure it fully answers my question though. Since "A command list embedded between parentheses runs as a subshell", I would expect the second `sleep` to run in a subshell (perhaps on the subshell's process since it's a built-in, rather than a subprocess of the subshell). However, in any case, I would have expected a subshell to exist, i.e. a Bash subprocess under the parent Bash process. For Snippet B above, this doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: Correction: Because `sleep` doesn't seem to be a built-in, I would expect the second `sleep` call in both snippets to run in a subprocess of the subshell process.

Comment: @bashful I took the liberty of hacking your code with my `$BASHPID` variable. Sadly the way you were doing it was not giving you the whole story I believe. See my added output in the answer.

Answer (score 4):

An additional note to @Gilles answer.

As said by Gilles: `The parentheses always start a subshell.`

However, the numbers that such sub-shell have might repeat:

```
$ (echo "$BASHPID and $$"; sleep 1)
2033 and 31679
$ (echo "$BASHPID and $$"; sleep 1)
2040 and 31679
$ (echo "$BASHPID and $$"; sleep 1)
2047 and 31679
```

As you can see, the $$ keeps repeating, and that is as expected, because (execute this command to find the correct `man bash` line):

```
$ LESS=+/'^ *BASHPID' man bash
```

> BASHPID
>   Expands to the process ID of the current bash process.  This differs from $$ under certain circumstances, such as subshells that do not require bash to be re-initialized.

That is: If the shell is not re-initialized, the $$ is the same.

Or with this:

```
$ LESS=+/'^ *Special Parameters' man bash
```

> Special Parameters
>   $      Expands to the process ID of the shell.  In a () subshell, it expands to the process ID of the current shell, not the subshell.

The `$$` is the ID of the current shell (not the subshell).

Comment: Nice trick for opening the bash manpage in a specific section