# Why is a variable visible in a subshell?

Tags: bash, shell, subshell

The Learning Bash Book mentions that a subshell will inherit only environment variables and file descriptors, etc., and that it will not inherit variables that are not exported:

```
$ var=15
$ (echo $var)
15
$ ./file # this file include the same command echo $var

$
```

As I know the shell will create two subshells for `()` and for `./file`, but why in the `()` case does the subshell identify the `var` variable although it is not exported and in the `./file` case it did not identify it?

```
# Strace for () 
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f24558b1a10) = 25617
# Strace for ./file
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f24558b1a10) = 25631
```

I tried to use `strace` to figure out how this happens and surprisingly I found that bash will use the same arguments for the clone system call, so this means that both the forked process in `()` and `./file` should have the same process address space of the parent, so why in the `()` case is the varible visible to the subshell and the same does not happen for the `./file` case, although the same arguments is based on the clone system call?

Comment: vinc17 say true, even you get pstree when you have subshell, you believe this matter.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The Learning Bash Book is wrong. Subshells inherit all variables. Even `$$` (the PID of the original shell) is kept. The reason is that for a subshell, the shell just forks and doesn't execute a new shell (on the contrary, when you type `./file`, a new command is executed, e.g. a new shell; in the strace output, look at `execve` and similar). So, basically, it's just a copy (with some documented differences).

Note: this is not specific to bash; this is true for any shell.

Comment: Oky but i tried now to lauch strace on the shell and i tried to execute ./file but i can't find any call for exec and so the address space should be the same for both processes so how this can be explained?

Comment: @user3718463 Did you use the `-f` option of `strace` to trace children too? That's necessary to find the exec's.

Comment: yup i figure it out thanks alot, i was missing the -f option, and so i can't find the exec sys call

Answer (score 20):

Either you or the book is confusing a subshell with a subprocess that is a shell.

Some shell constructs result in the shell [forking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_(system_call)) a child process. Under Linux, `fork` is a special case of the more general `clone` system call, which you observed in the `strace` log. The child runs a part of the shell script. The child process is called a **subshell**. The most direct such construct is `command1 &`: `command1` runs in a subshell, and subsequent commands run in the parent shell. Other constructs that create a subshell include command substitution `$(command2)` and pipes `command3 | command4` (`command3` runs in a subshell, `command4` runs in a subshell in most shells but not in ksh or zsh).

A subshell is a copy of the parent process, so it has not only the same environment variables, but also all the same internal definitions: variables (including `$$`, the process ID of the original shell process), functions, aliases, options, etc. Before executing the code in the subshell, bash sets the variable `BASHPID` to the process ID of the child process.

When you run `./file`, this executes an external command. First, the shell forks a child process; then this child process [executes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exec_(computing)) (with the `execve` system call) the executable file `./file`. A child process inherits process attributes of its parents: environment, current directory, etc. Internal aspects of the application are lost in the `execve` call: non-exported variables, functions, etc. are bash notions that the kernel doesn't know about, and they are lost when bash executes another program. Even if that other program happens to be a bash script, it is executed by a new instance of bash that doesn't know or care that its parent process happens to also be an instance of bash. Thus a shell variable (non-exported variable) doesn't survive `execve`.

Comment: This answer cleared up quite a few things for me. The only thing I don't understand is this sentence in the second paragraph: "The child runs a part of the shell script." What shell script is being referred to?

Comment: @flow2k The script (i.e. the program) that the shell is interpreting.