# Behaviour for output of Command Substitution working with String variable with Pipes

Tags: bash, command-line, stdout, command-substitution

For simplicity and how source/input of this post for the coming scenarios, observe the following

```
java --version
openjdk 11.0.13 2021-10-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-11.0.13+8 (build 11.0.13+8)
OpenJDK Client VM Temurin-11.0.13+8 (build 11.0.13+8, mixed mode)
```

Just in case `java` command shows the following

```
 -version     print product version to the error  stream and exit
--version     print product version to the output stream and exit
```

That's why I use the latter for the following commands scenarios:

Therefore with:

```
#1
java --version | head -n1
openjdk 11.0.13 2021-10-19

#2
x=$(java --version | head -n1)
echo $x
openjdk 11.0.13 2021-10-19
```

Until here all is ok and expected.

Now taking in consideration the following:

- [Behaviour of bash command substitution with command from string in variable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/388345/behaviour-of-bash-command-substitution-with-command-from-string-in-variable)

**Note** I need the approach shown in the previous link to build complex commands according with some options defined by the user through input - assume a command with parameters chosen by the user.

Therefore with:

```
x="java --version | head -n1"
echo $($x)
OpenJDK Client VM Temurin-11.0.13+8 (build 11.0.13+8, mixed mode) <--- not expected
```

The output now is different. Why? How to fix it? or what is missing?

I need the same output as Command Substitution *without* String

**Extra Question**

- Is valid use command substitution with String as parameter? or is a bad practice?

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of the question you linked to; can you [edit] it to be clear on what you're asking that isn't addressed there?

Comment: @steeldriver Is that not the same as "the `;` (and subsequent arguments) will be passed as literal parameters to the `echo` command"?

Comment: Yes, I have problems with the `|` pipe. Is not considered. I did do a research and sadly `eval` is _evil_

Comment: @MichaelHomer ah yes fair enough

Comment: @MichaelHomer title edited to do mention about pipes. The other link post is without pipes and the commands used are simple `echo`

Comment: Ok. It is actually a duplicate, though.

Comment: It's _definitely_ a dupe of the question that you link to. The second line executes `echo $('java' '-version' '|' 'head' '-n1')`, which the accepted answer to the dupe explains.

Comment: I found that `alias x="java --version | head -n1"` works, I am going to do a research if it has some drawbacks as `eval`