# Why does subcommand take the PID of parent when I don't use exec

Tags: bash, process, exec

I executed `bash -c "ps && ps"` and got the following output:

```
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
25544 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
26562 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
26563 pts/0    00:00:00 ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
25544 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
26562 pts/0    00:00:00 ps
```

And I'm confused why is the PID of last `ps` the same as the PID of `bash` which spawned it (`26562`).

This seems to always affect the last command (if I have 3 commands given to `bash` then the first 2 have different PIDs and and last reuses the `bash` one).

Shouldn't the PIDs be different and shouldn't I be able to see it this behavior only if I prefix it with `exec`?.

Comment: Also: [Rule for invoking subshell in Bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/41382/70524)